# C# Mongo driver: Update query using joins and UpdateManyAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have 2 collections

ProductCategory

> _id
>   name
>   active

Product

> _id
>   CategoryId
>   DateUpdated

I can do the update in one collection by creating a filter and using UpdateManyAsync, like this:

```
var update = Builders<ProductCategory>.Update
                .Set(x => x.Active ,false);


var filter = Builders<ProductCategory>.Filter.Where(
                x => x.Active == true);

var result = await Collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);
```

Now I want to update Active field on ProductCategory if any documents with DateUpdated more than 1 day compared to current date

it may the same as sql query:

```
UPDATE A
SET active = false
FROM ProductCategory A
JOIN Product B
    ON A._id= B.CategoryId
WHERE DATEDIFF(Getdate(), B.DateCreated) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik you cannot update entities based on the result of a lookup/join in mongodb via a single command. instead you'd have to first retrieve the IDs of categories and then do the update operation like below:

```cs
var inactiveCatIDs = collection.AsQueryable()
                               .Where(p => p.DateUpdated <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
                               .Select(p => p.CategoryID)
                               .ToArray();

collection.UpdateMany(c => inactiveCatIDs.Contains(c.ID),
                      Builders<ProductCategory>.Update.Set(c => c.Active, false));
```

here's a test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Product : Entity
    {
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
        public string CategoryID { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductCategory : Entity
    {
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            var cat1 = new ProductCategory { Active = true }; cat1.Save();
            var cat2 = new ProductCategory { Active = true }; cat2.Save();

            (new[] { new Product
            {
                CategoryID = cat1.ID,
                DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1.5)
            },
            new Product
            {
                CategoryID = cat2.ID,
                DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow
            }}).Save(); ;

            var inactiveCatIDs = DB.Queryable<Product>()
                                   .Where(p => p.DateUpdated <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
                                   .Select(p => p.CategoryID)
                                   .ToArray();

            DB.Update<ProductCategory>()
              .Match(c => inactiveCatIDs.Contains(c.ID))
              .Modify(c => c.Active, false)
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've decided to make schema changes as maybe it not good to make "join" thing in non-relational database like mongodb.

Comment: both joins vs. embedded have their pros and cons. you just gotta experiment with what works best for your application.